# Is there a way to improve this dynamics ax update job

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I'm working on an AX 2009 installation. The job is to update the WMSOrderTrans table. Here is what I have got so far:

```
WMSOrderTrans   wmsOrderTrans;
;

while select wmsOrderTrans
{
    if (wmsOrderTrans.BBBpackingSlipExists())
    {
        ttsBegin;
        wmsOrderTrans.selectForUpdate(true);
        wmsOrderTrans.BBBPackingSlipExists  =   NoYes::Yes;
        wmsOrderTrans.doUpdate();
        ttsCommit;
    }
}
```

The job takes about an hour to finish on the test system. This makes me worry about the **performance** on the production system.

At the moment the code has been written like this to have minimal locking issues (selectForUpdate is done for each row if it should be updated and is then immediatly committed). The reason is, that users will be working on the system, when the job is running.

My question is, **if there is a reasonable way to implement this job in a way with less transaction overhead.**

```
while select forUpdate ...
```

... does not seem to  be an option, because it would lock the table until the job is finished.

Any input is appreciated.

---

This is the code for the BBBPackingSlipExists method:

```
display boolean BBBpackingSlipExists()
    {
    InventDim               inventDimCur;
    InventDim               inventDimPackSlip;
    InventTrans             inventTransPackSlip;

    ;

    select firstonly RecId from inventTransPackSlip
        where inventTransPackSlip.InventTransId == this.inventTransId
            && (inventTransPackSlip.StatusIssue == StatusIssue::Deducted
                || inventTransPackSlip.StatusIssue == StatusIssue::Sold)
            && !inventTransPackSlip.PackingSlipReturned
        exists join inventDimCur
            where inventDimCur.inventDimId == this.inventDimId
        exists join inventDimPackSlip
            where inventDimPackSlip.inventDimId == inventTransPackSlip.inventDimId
                && inventDimCur.inventSerialId  == inventDimPackSlip.inventSerialId
    ;
if (inventTransPackSlip.RecId != 0 && this.isReserved)
{
    return true;
}
return false;
```

}

Comment: good question. I'm editing the question and adding the code for this method

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This looks like a prime candidate to convert to [set based logic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa673589%28v=ax.50%29.aspx), I'd go for something like this. Please note that the job isn't tested at all since I don't have a 2009 environment handy (this doesn't even compile on 2012) so if you need to change the code feel free to edit it into my answer.

Note that the isreserved check is built into the query as well as the exists joins from the packingslipexists method

```
static void Job250(Args _args)
{
    WMSOrderTrans           wmsOrderTrans;
    InventDim               inventDimCur;
    InventDim               inventDimPackSlip;
    InventTrans             inventTransPackSlip;
    ;
    wmsOrderTrans.skipDatabaseLog(true);
    wmsOrderTrans.skipDataMethods(true);
    wmsOrderTrans.skipEvents(true);
    update_recordset wmsOrderTrans setting BBBPackingSlipExists  = NoYes::Yes
        where wmsOrderTrans.isReserved
        exists join inventTransPackSlip
        where inventTransPackSlip.InventTransId == wmsOrderTrans.inventTransId
          && (inventTransPackSlip.StatusIssue == StatusIssue::Deducted
           || inventTransPackSlip.StatusIssue == StatusIssue::Sold)
          && !inventTransPackSlip.PackingSlipReturned
        exists join inventDimCur
        where inventDimCur.inventDimId == wmsOrderTrans.inventDimId
        exists join inventDimPackSlip
        where inventDimPackSlip.inventDimId == inventTransPackSlip.inventDimId
           && inventDimCur.inventSerialId  == inventDimPackSlip.inventSerialId;       
}
```

See the documentation on [update_recordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa674382.aspx) and why the [skip* methods might be necessary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa849875.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the links for the according information. The performance gain of this solution is tremendous.

Comment: @elToro out of curiosity, what's the timing now (instead of an hour)?

Comment: about two minutes :-)

Comment: @elToro Set based logic is always a magnitude faster than cursor based operations

Comment: they are gonna be my favourite way from now on